# select range in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection

Not able to select the range clearly in the macro. 
My data range is B4:N80( data always starts from B4 and it can go upto any cell)
so i am creating macro to select this range

```
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(4, 2).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
```

With the above code am not able to select the entire data from B4 to "XX"

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: `Rows.count` and  `Columns.Count` reference the `ActiveSheet`, not the `DSheet` unless it happens to be de active sheet.

Comment: `Set PRange = DSheet.Range(DSheet.Cells(4, 2),DSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))` and `PRange.Select`

Comment: 99% of the time you never need to `Select` anything. Are you doing anything with the `Selection` afterwards?

Comment: i m creating pivot using PRANGE (B4:XX) as data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
Sheets("DSheet").Activate
Range("B4").Select
Set PRange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
```

Comment: This should work and is a good idea actually. There is some more room for improvement, you could write this as
`Sheets("Dsheet").Range("B4", Sheets("Dsheet").Range("B4").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select`
This should do all of the desired actions in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Declare all your variables, and use  `.Select` if you're just trying to select the range.

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet

    Set DSheet = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(4, 2).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    PRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried but only B,C,D columns getting selected .. I have data upto Z columns

Comment: @haribabu I edited it, try it now. `LastCol` was being defined by the values in row 2 `LastCol = DSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`, if your values do not begin until row 4, that would screw up your range.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to select the range you need to add

```
PRange.Select
```

I also think your parameters will be off by a bit. The correct range would be

```
Set PRange = DSheet.cells(4, 2).Resize(LastRow - 4, LastCol - 2)
```

Edit: Your parameters will be off since the range you're starting at is B4. So if your data goes down to B10 for example, LastRow will be set to the row number with the last data entry, in this case 10. Now if you want to expand your desired range to include all data entries you don't have to resize by 10 (LastRow), but by 6 (LastRow - 4), since 4 + 6 = 10. In your example it would be 4 + 10 = 14, which is higher than your data entries actually reach.